# Why does rye flour dough require more water?

Tags: bread, dough, rye

Most discussions I have seen on the internet recommend increasing water content when substituting wheat flour with rye flour.

I find this a bit puzzling since I always thought that hydration of the dough should be based on the protein content - more gluten means stronger dough, which means it stretches without tearing even at higher hydration.

Rye flour (at least the one I have) is very high in carbohydrates but low in protein content, so why is more water required?

Comment: This feels the wrong way round - "when substituting wheat flour for rye flour." You mean rye for wheat?

Comment: no, i mean rye. see for example [this](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/33652/hydration-adjustment-when-adding-rye-flour).

Comment: Still not clear. "To substitute **x** for **y**" is to use x where y was originally specified. Same on a football field (or anywhere) New player x was substituted for player y who had to retire because of injury.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- unfortunately, "substitute" gets used backwards these days. Usually it's "substitute X with Y", analogous to "replace X with Y", but that seems to have corrupted "substitute X for Y" to also mean "replace X with Y". Sigh.

Comment: oh, good catch @Tetsujin! I misused the [expression](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23360/substitute-x-for-y). I will edit the question to make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that higher-protein flours are capable of absorbing more water.  However, protein is not the only thing that affects water absorption.  [In addition, according to Bakerpedia, there are](https://bakerpedia.com/processes/water-absorption/):

- starches & [pentosans](https://bakerpedia.com/ingredients/pentosan/)
- enzymes
- flour grind

Rye flour, while low in protein, is [very high in water-absorbing pentosans](https://www.cooksillustrated.com/how_tos/6516-baking-with-rye-flour-for-longer-lasting-bread).  Hence the need and ability to add more water.